# Bash check if file was modified within date range

Tags: python, bash, time, posix, epoch

I have a script that checks to see if a cert, (.cer file), is within 14 days of expiring, and if it is, it will archive the old cert request, generate a new one, and send it to the middleware team. The thought occurs though, that if this script runs on a cron at midnight every night, what's to prevent it from sending another cert request to the middleware team on each subsequent night within the date range (within 14 days of cert expiring)?

I'd like to check the time stamp on the .csr file, and it it's been replaced or modified within 14 days of the cert, (.cer file), expiring, then do nothing, else archive csr, gencsr, mailcsr. Here's the main routine of the script:

```
if python -c "
import datetime
import sys
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
key_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%b %d %Y')
difference = key_time - current_time
sys.exit(0 if difference.days < 14 else 1)
" "$( keytool -printcert -file "$1" | sed '4q;d' | awk '{print $11,$12,$15}' )";then archive;gencert;mail;else echo "Cert is still current";fi
```

I'm currently on `Oracle Linux Server release 7.9`

It would seem that the next course of action is to save the output of the .cer file check to a variable in epoch time, save the output of a timestamp check in a file in epoch time to a variable or a flag file, and then compare the two. `If timestamp on .csr is -gt (14 days of .cer expiring), then do nothing; else archive; gencsr; mailcsr; fi`.

And the implementation is something like:

```
domain=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\.cer//'`
csr_time_stamp=$(<epoch time of modified date>)
cer_exp_date=$(<epoch time of .cer exp. date>)
if [ $csr_time_stamp > $cer_time_stamp ] && [ -f flagfiles/$domain.csr ];then echo $csr_time_stamp >> flagfiles/$domain.csr;else archivecsr; gencsr; mailcsr;fi
```

But I still didn't check the flag file for the date stamp, is that an unnecessary step if you put both dates in a variable each time?

The output of the keytool command:

```
keytool -printcert -file fqdn.domainname.com.cer | sed '4q;d' | awk '{print $11,$12,$15}'
Jan 24 2018
```

The output of the timestamp on the .csr file:

```
stat fqdn.domainname.com.csr | grep Modify | awk '{print $2}'
2023-03-13
```

With the excellent help from @markp-fuso, here is the code I used:

```
domain=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\.cer//'`
OUTPUT_DIR=<obfuscated>
archive=<obfuscated>

# convert keytool/expire date to epoch; could probably streamline this a bit

keytool_dt=$(keytool -printcert -file "$1" | sed '4q;d' | awk '{print $11,$12,$15}') # eg: 'Jan 24 2018'
exp_dt=$(date -d "${keytool_dt}" "+%s")      # convert to epoch seconds

# calculate number of secs in 14 day range

dt_range=$((14 * 60 * 60 * 24))              # 1209600

# current epoch - one of the following:

now_dt=$(date "+%s")                         # spawns a subprocess

#printf -v now_dt '%(%s)T'                   # does not spawn a subprocess; requires bash 3.1+

# last modification date of csr file, in epoch seconds

mod_dt=$(stat -c "%Y" "$domain".csr)

echo "domain.csr: $domain.csr"

echo "now_dt: $now_dt exp_dt: $exp_dt dt_range: $dt_range exp_dt: $exp_dt mod_dt: $mod_dt"

if (( $now_dt > ($exp_dt + $dt_range) ))     # cert has, or will soon, expire
then
   if (( ($now_dt - $mod_dt) > $dt_range ))  # csr last mod date was more than 14 days ago
   then
       echo "cert expired: generate new csr"
   else
       echo "cert expired: new csr pending"
   fi
else
   echo "cert is valid"
fi
```

Now it works, I had to change `now_dt` back to what you used in your code and mod_dt wasn't declared, I was tired at that point:

```
now_dt: 1678893896
domain.csr: <obfuscated>.csr
now_dt: 1678893896 exp_dt: 1516780800 dt_range: 1209600 exp_dt: 1516780800 mod_dt: 1678767236
cert expired: new csr pending
```

Comment: What you describe at the end sounds good to me. Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: You can do date math in `bash` (easily) if your `date` command supports the `--date=` option (maybe `myDate=$(date --date="now + 14 days") +%Y%m%d` gets you started).  OR I would expect there is a `python` packages that gives the `keytool` features you need (and email, etc). So write your in one loanguage or the other). Good luck.

Comment: at this point the code is getting quite convoluted; there's likely a more streamlined solution but would require some basic details, eg, complete output from the `keytool` call (make note of which portion of the output is of interest), your `date --version`, your `stat --version`

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, I added the relevant outputs to the original post.

Comment: so your sample certificate expired 5+ yrs ago?  which in turn means, what, every 14 days you're generating a new csr?

Comment: @mattfreake, I don't know how to do the part where you check the exp date of the cert, and if it's within 14 days of expiring, and the .csr file hasn't been modified within the date range of (less than 14 days of .cer expiring); then generate a new cert request and mail it to the middleware team; else if the .csr file has been modified within (14 days of the .cer expiring);then write the time stamp of the .csr file to a flag file and make sure you don't generate another cert request when the script runs each night during the (within 14 days of .cer expiring time period).

Comment: @markp-fuso, that's just an old cert I'm practicing with in a practice or test environment. The script does what it's supposed to do, it will generate a cert request when the .cer file is within 14 days of expiring, I'm trying to prevent it from generating and mailing another cert request each night while the .cer is still within 14 days of expiring on each subsequent night until I replace the old .cer file with the new one.

Comment: fwiw, once you introduce `awk` there's typically no need for `sed` and `grep`; GNU core utlis version of `stat` has the `-c` option for pulling out specific file details (eg, `%y` and `%Y` for last modification date) so no need for `grep` and/or `awk`

Comment: Okay thanks @markp-fuso for all your excellent help.

Comment: you've hardcoded a really old date (21 Oct 1973) for 'now'; the latest update shows`now_dt == 21 Oct 1973` while `exp_dt == 24 Jan 2018`; in other words ... 'now_dt' is ~45 yrs *before* the `exp_dt` so, yeah, the cert is good ... and will be good for the next ~45 yrs

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, I put your now_dt back and it works, and I somehow left out the declaration of the mod_dt. So obviously it wasn't going to work. it works now, and thanks again for an excellent script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General approach:

- obtain various datetime stamps in epoch format, placing in separate variables
- perform conditionals/tests against these epoch variables
- OP has access to GNU core utils (for `date -d` and `stat -c` support)

One approach:

```
# convert keytool/expire date to epoch; could probably steamline this a bit
# but would need complete keytool output; for now we'll work with what OP 
# has provided in the question:

keytool_dt=$(keytool | sed | awk)            # eg: 'Jan 24 2018'
exp_dt=$(date -d "${keytool_dt}" "+%s")      # convert to epoch seconds

# calculate number of secs in 14 day range

dt_range=$((14 * 60 * 60 * 24))              # 1209600

# current epoch - one of the following:

now_dt=$(date "+%s")                         # spawns a subprocess
printf -v now_dt '%(%s)T'                    # does not spawn a subprocess; requires bash 3.1+

# last modification date of csr file, in epoch seconds

mod_dt=$(stat -c "%Y" file.csr)
```

Now the comparisons:

```
if (( now_dt > (exp_dt - dt_range) ))        # cert has, or will soon, expire
then
   if (( (now_dt - mod_dt) > dt_range ))     # csr last mod date was more than 14 days ago
   then
       echo "cert expired: generate new csr"
   else
       echo "cert expired: new csr pending"
   fi
else
   echo "cert is valid"
fi
```

**NOTE:**

- I haven't done an exhaustive set of validations on the conditionals
- not sure that I've covered all of OP's scenarios
- with the various (epoch) numbers in hand it shouldn't be to hard for OP to (re)write the conditionals as needed

Comment: The complete output of the keytool command when you grep the line with the string `until` is: `Valid from: Mon Mar 13 17:00:00 PDT 2017 until: Wed Jan 24 15:59:59 PST 2018`. Thanks for your excellent help.

Comment: Oops, @markp-fuso, first let me say this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not sure if the answer I got though on my first attempt was valid: `cert is valid`, I ran this against that old 2018 cert and I believe the results should have been `cert expired: new csr pending` shouldn't it have been?

Comment: would need to see the exact code you ran along with all of the actual values in the variables; with `keytool_dt='Jan 24 2018'` and `mod_dt=1678718522` (the last mod date - `2023-03-13 09:42:02.072758000 -0500` - of a file in my system), I get `cert expired: new csr pending`

Comment: also, with an epoch number in hand, you can convert it into a human readable format with `date -d @`, eg, `date -d @1678718522` and `date -d "@${exp_dt}"`; you can use this, for example, to verify `exp_dt` maps back to `Jan 24 2018` ...

Comment: I'll put the results, values in variables, and the code in my original post.

Comment: I see what it is, the `stat -c` didn't work on the csr file, let me fix that.